# Unknown file system unnsupported drive / partition?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, mount, hard-drive, ntfs

I have a 1TB HDD that I use on Windows for file storage, and I would like to share this storage between Windows and Ubuntu (dual boot).
But I can't seem to be able to mount this drive in Ubuntu. I can only see the drive in GParted and in the Discs utility. In both it is stated that the file system is unknown. I've already tried mounting it in several ways, but with no success.
It seems that the drive, although NTFS formatted in windows, is somewhat formatted to be a storage device in Windows.

So, the real question is, is there a way to convert this HDD or partition without losing data, to be functional in both operating systems?

Comment: Have you turned off fast startup in Windows? If not, turn it off by following this guide and then try to mount your disk again.

Comment: If *windows* fast-boot is on; the file-system will be in an inconsistent state (and thus being seen as *unknown* should not be unexpected) as part of the data for it is in the fast-boot (hibernate) save.  It'll be recognized when that fast-boot.hibernate file is loaded, ie. in windows but in other OSes only after fastboot is disabled (and the data is actually written to disk partition fully).

Comment: Thanks for the quick answers, I'll check later at home if fast startup is turned on or not, and I'll report back.

Comment: I just checked and Windows fast boot is already off, so the problem persists... any other idea?

Comment: @Kriptonboy, we need a little diagnostic. Please right-click on your Start icon at bottom left, then choose Disk Management. Take a screenshot, save it as a file, then upload it to http://imgur.com or some other open image hosting site.  Come back here, click [edit] and paste the address to your picture into your question.

Comment: I´m afraid i just messed up the drive by using ntfsfix on ubuntu.. now the partition / drive wont show up in windows. I'm trying now to recover the partition.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all who tried to help, I ended up formating the drive and restoring the data from a backup with minor file loss.
I've messed up pretty bad with the tools trying to recover the drive /partition.

Good news is that now it actually works on both OS (win10 & Ubuntu)

Thanks